# Wordpress Plugin for Parse.com

Tags: php, wordpress, parse-platform

I just want to ask very basic question. I want to make a plugin using php-sdk of Parse.com to retrieve data from Parse.com. my first question Is it possible ??

if Yes? then just tell me how I will maintain the sessions in the plugin for Parse.com.

I know its very general question but please anybody answer me.

Comment: Yes I have solved it.

Comment: if you can please share some basic code with how you did it, thanks